# GSON deserialization of object arrays

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I have a class with the following attributes

```
public class JenkinsServer
{
  private String                          url;

  private String                          mode;
  private String                          nodeName;
  private String                          nodeDescription;
  private String                          description;

  private boolean                         useSecurity;
  private boolean                         quietingDown;

  private JenkinsServerView               primaryView;

  private List< JenkinsJob >        jobs;
  private List< JenkinsServerView > views;
}
```

Now I want GSON to deserialize/map a json document to it. It works well, except for my lists - they are empty. The json document looks as follows (snippet):

```
"jobs": [
{
  "name": "AnotherJob",
  "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/job/AnotherJob/",
  "color": "disabled"
},
{
  "name": "AnotherJob2",
  "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/job/Build%20CI%20Build/",
  "color": "blue"
},

"views": [
    {
      "name": "-All Views",
      "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/view/-All%Views/"
    },
    {
      "name": "Alle",
      "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/"
    },
```

The mapping works, even for the single instance of

> JenkinsServerView primaryView

but not for the Lists. I'm starting the mapping this way:

```
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
JenkinsServer server = gson.fromJson( reader, JenkinsServer.class );
```

Comment: @ashokramcse No, just empty lists (ArrayList).

Comment: It clearly means that your JSON is not right when you are serializing it to JenkinsServer class.

Answer (score 0):

looks your json data that you are trying to parse is invalid.

In your json **jobs** and **views** are arrays and both of them doesn't have the closing brace at the end.

The valid json will be as follows: (Observe the closing braces at the end of the array)

```
{
    "jobs": [
        {
            "name": "AnotherJob",
            "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/job/AnotherJob/",
            "color": "disabled"
        },
        {
            "name": "AnotherJob2",
            "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/job/Build%20CI%20Build/",
            "color": "blue"
        }
    ],
    "views": [
        {
            "name": "-All Views",
            "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/view/-All%Views/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Alle",
            "url": "https://build.example.com/jenkins/"
        }
    ]
}
```